# Overlay Panel iPad

Tags: ios, view, panel

I am trying to create a panel which slides over my views to display more content very similar to the app store on the ipad:

[image: http://0.tqn.com/d/ipad/1/0/g/5/-/-/ipad-app-like.png]

Is there a class for something like this or will i have to create it from scratch?

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how to do this, use:

```
UIViewController *sampleView = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[sampleView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[self presentViewController:sampleView animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

If you want square corners like on the app store you can use:

```
self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
```

In the viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated method of the UIViewController you use. You will need to import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h.

Answer (score 0):

Uicontainerview is what I would use. you can find this control under 'U'.